# How to set the labels size on a pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, pie-chart

I want to have labels with small size on a  piechart in python to improve visibility
here is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frac=[1.40 , 10.86 , 19.31 , 4.02 , 1.43 , 2.66 , 4.70 , 0.70 , 0.13 , 1.48, 32.96 , 1.11 , 13.30 , 5.86]
labels=['HO0900344', 'HO0900331', 'HO0900332', 'HO0900354', 
'HO0900358', 'HO0900374', 'HO0900372', 'HO0900373', 
'HO0900371', 'HO0900370', 'HO0900369', 'HO0900356', 
'HO0900353', 'HO0900343']

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis('equal')
colors=('b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'burlywood', 'w')
ax.pie(frac,colors=colors ,labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can change the font size of the labels.

You can [dynamically changet the rc settings](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings). Add the following at the top of your script:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 9.0
```

Or you can modify the labels after they have been created. When you call `ax.pie` it [returns a tuple](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) of (patches, texts, autotexts). As an example, modify your final few lines of code as follows:

```
patches, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(frac, colors=colors, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
texts[0].set_fontsize(4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: To set the size of all labels at once, use a list comprehension: `[ _.set_fontsize(4) for _ in texts ]`.

Answer (score 161):

The simplest way to change the font size on a pie chart is directly via the [`textprops` argument](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) in the `pie()` function. Using the code above add it like so:

```
ax.pie(frac, colors=colors ,labels=labels, 
       autopct='%1.1f%%', textprops={'fontsize': 14})
```

That way you can just pass in a dictionary with your desired fontsize (e.g., 14). No messing around with `rcParams` or return values from the function call.

Comment: This should be the top answer

Comment: How to change label's  font size while leaving autopct's font size unchanged?