# How to change text font size of labels in a pie chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to increase the text size of labels like Carbon, Oxygen in my pie chart.

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

elements_mass =[43,16,7,0.78,0.14,1.8,1.0,0.14,0.10,0.095]
elements_name =["Oxygen","Carbon","Hydrogen","Phosphorus","Potassium","Nitrogen","Calcium","Sulfur","Sodium","Chlorine"]

plt.axis("equal")

plt.pie(elements_mass,labels=elements_name, radius=4, autopct='%0.3f%%',pctdistance = 0.8,shadow=False, explode =[0.1,0.09,0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.3,0.7,0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the labels size on a pie chart in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082345/how-to-set-the-labels-size-on-a-pie-chart-in-python)